# keeping null values as they are in panda dataframe columns while assigning type to them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda data frame and want to import it to bigquery using to_gbq(). Some of the columns have null value and I want to keep them as they are without replacing null value to nan, None or other string. for example if I use the below line if replace null values to 0. Is there any way to keep null values while changing their type?

```
 df['ViewersStart']=df['ViewersStart'].fillna(0).astype('int64')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `loc`, to only replace where `ViewersStart` is not null:

```
df.loc[df.ViewersStart.notnull(),'ViewersStart'] = df.loc[df.ViewersStart.notnull(),'ViewersStart'].astype('int64')
```

**Example**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ViewersStart':['1','5',6,np.nan,'12']})
>>> df
  ViewersStart
0            1
1            5
2            6
3          NaN
4           12

# Notice that your column is a mix of strings, ints and NaN
>>> df.values
array([['1'],
       ['5'],
       [6],
       [nan],
       ['12']], dtype=object)

df.loc[df.ViewersStart.notnull(),'ViewersStart'] = df.loc[df.ViewersStart.notnull(),'ViewersStart'].astype('int64')

>>> df
  ViewersStart
0            1
1            5
2            6
3          NaN
4           12

# Notice that all non-null values are now ints
>>> df.values
array([[1],
       [5],
       [6],
       [nan],
       [12]], dtype=object)
```